# How to set item selected on loading uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, collectionview, nsindexpath

I want to set scroll to selected item on view is loading. I have implement like below. but it crashes.

```
self.collectinView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(self.selected_indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

this is error I'm getting:

> 2017-03-23 19:52:45.918645 com.CodeZync.Taxi.iOSClient[7936:1702109] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}' *** First throw call stack: (0x1d09cdf7 0x1c2ff077 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: collectinView is missing an o, but I doubt that is your problem. selected_indexPath is not a properly formatted variable for swift syntax, but that is just cosmetic. I would appreciate more code surrounding this line. Perhaps you could post your viewDidLoad? The error message would also be handy!

Comment: When do you reload collection, on viewDidLoad or web service API call response?

Answer (score 0):

So the indexPath is not visible yet. Make sure you have added the appropriate data into the collectionView, and then do a `collectionView.reloadData()` inside of `viewDidLoad()`

Then in `viewDidAppear()` place your line and also if you wanted to select the cell like you said, add this:

```
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally))
```

Doing the selecting and scrolling in `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` after you call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` will make the animation visible.

The reason for your bug is that the collection view is empty when you call the selection so it crashes.